# CollectionView within a CollectionView: Using didSelectItemAt to performSegue

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView within a collectionView and I want to be able to select a cell in the 2nd collectionView to perform a segue to another ViewController.

Currently, when I select a cell, I get the following message:
"  Receiver ... has no segue with identifier 'ToVC2'. "

However, I have used this segue/identifier from other UIButtons and it works.

---

I have two ViewControllers: ViewController1 and ViewController2.

On ViewController1, there is a collectionView ("categoryCollectionView") which has vertical scrolling.

Within categoryCollectionView, there is another collectionView ("eventCollectionView") which allows horizontal scrolling.

The two collectionViews are set up and working correctly for numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAt. I now want to be able to select a cell within eventCollectionView, and cause a segue from ViewController1 to ViewController2.

I have added a function in ViewController1:

```
func segueToViewController2(event: Event){

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVC2", sender: event)

}
```

Within eventCollectionView's didSelectItemAt, I have tried the following:

```
var viewController1: ViewController1? = ViewController1()
viewController1.segueToViewController2(event: eventSelected)
```

When I select a cell, I get the following error message:

'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'ToVC2''

However, this function performs the segue correctly if called from a regular UIButton on ViewController1 (therefore I know the issue is not that there is no segue / the identifier is wrong.) I believe the issue is that the function is being called from a collectionView within a collectionView.

Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that when you call `var viewController1: ViewController1? = ViewController1()`, you are initializing a new instance of `ViewController1`. This is probably not what you are meaning to do. Based on what you have said, you should pass a reference down the hierarchy of collection views you have created so that your didSelect can call the segue function on the original instance of `ViewController1`. Ideally, you would use a design pattern like delegation to do this.

Comment: I figured out how to pass the reference down the hierarchy and it worked! I stored a ( var viewController1: ViewController1! ) within the cell of each of the two collectionViews. This way when I call the segue, it knows exactly where to call it from. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: No problem. Just as a style tip, it is not normally good practice to pass a reference like that down because it gives the collection view too much access to the view controller. I would suggest using a delegate to hide some functionality. Also, if you store a `var` referencing the view controller in one of the view controller's subviews, you will have created a retain cycle which will cause a memory leak. You should at least change your code to `weak var` to create a weak reference rather than a strong one.